# Discord.py Problem with role.kick_members, I get an error

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to read the kick permission of all the roles on my discord server, but when I do so I get this error "'Role' object has no attribute 'kick_members'". https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=kick_members#discord.Permissions The code is this one:

```
@client.command()
async def Check_kick_permission(ctx):
    for role in ctx.guild.roles:
        print(str(role.role.kick_members))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are accessing the [role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Role) object incorrectly.

You do the following:

```
print(str(role.role.kick_members))
```

But the role object does not have a role object in it. Thus the second role is unnecessary and will cause problems.

When you change this to the following:

```
print(str(role.permissions.kick_members))
```

It will work. As you are asking what permissions the role has. And then ask if it has the [kick_members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=permission#discord.Permissions.kick_members) [permission](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=permission#discord.Permissions).

For more information read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the permissions from the role via `role.permissions` [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=kick_members#discord.Role.permissions)